# RMI Stubs: Force host-value on client side

Tags: java, rmi

We would like to access the same RMI-server from different hosts in our network (dev-pc via ssh-tunnel, jenkins-server via direct connection). The problem is that the RMI-host is known under different names on the different client hosts.

This is not a problem when we connect to the registry, because we can set the target host name like this:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("hostname", 10099, new CustomSslRMIClientSocketFactory());
```

But when we lookup the remote object like below, it contains the wrong hostname.

```
HelloRemote hello = (HelloRemote) registry.lookup(HelloRemote.class.getSimpleName());
```

In the debugger I can observe that the host is like needed on the Registry object, but not on the Stub:
[image: debugger view on registry and stub]

We get a connection timeout as soon as we call a method on the Stub. If I manually change the host value to `localhost` in the debugger the method invocation succeeds.

I'm aware that I can set `java.rmi.server.hostname` on the server side but then the connection from jenkins does not work anymore.
The simplest solution would be that I force RMI to use the same host as for the registry for all Stubs retrieved from that registry. Is there a better way than replacing the host-value in the Stub via reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately RMI has a deeply built-in assumption that the server host has a single 'most public' IP address or hostname. This explains the `java.rmi.server.hostname` fiasco. If your system doesn't comply you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by EJP there seems to be no elegant out-of-the-box solution.
I can think of two unelegant ones:

1. Changing the network configuration on every client host in order to redirect traffic to the non-reachable ip to localhost instead.
2. Changing the host value on the "hello"-object via Reflection.

I went for the second option because I'm in a test environment and the code in question will not go productive anyways. I wouldn't recommend to do this otherwise, because this code might break with future versions of java and won't work if a Security Manager is in place.

However, here my working code:

```
private static void forceRegistryHostNameOnStub(Object registry, Object stub) {
    try {
        String regHost = getReferenceToInnerObject(registry, "ref", "ref", "ep", "host").toString();

        Object stubEp = getReferenceToInnerObject(stub, "h", "ref", "ref", "ep");
        Field fStubHost = getInheritedPrivateField(stubEp, "host");
        fStubHost.setAccessible(true);
        fStubHost.set(stubEp, regHost);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("Applying the registry host to the Stub failed.", e);
    }
}

private static Object getReferenceToInnerObject(Object from, String... objectHierarchy) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Object ref = from;
    for (String fieldname : objectHierarchy) {
        Field f = getInheritedPrivateField(ref, fieldname);
        f.setAccessible(true);
        ref = f.get(ref);
    }
    return ref;
}

private static Field getInheritedPrivateField(Object from, String fieldname) throws NoSuchFieldException {
    Class<?> i = from.getClass();
    while (i != null && i != Object.class) {
        try {
            return i.getDeclaredField(fieldname);
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            // ignore
        }
        i = i.getSuperclass();
    }
    return from.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldname);
}
```

The method invocation on the Stub succeeds now:

```
Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry("hostname", 10099, new CustomSslRMIClientSocketFactory());
HelloRemote hello = (HelloRemote) registry.lookup(HelloRemote.class.getSimpleName());
forceRegistryHostNameOnStub(registry, hello); // manipulate the stub
hello.doSomething(); // succeeds
```